# Android app opens multiple times using Firebase

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have been scratching my head for hours now, I am using Firebase authentication in my android app and for some reason it keeps popping up randomly it opens multiple times basically, after researching I found that it is probably the method AuthStateListener.

I have tried adding a flag like people who were having the same problem but to no avail, where should I start my activity if the Firebase user or authentication does not equal to null without the app spontaneously opening up by itself. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
mAuthListner= new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                //Log.i("User1",firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().toString());
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class))
                    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));

                //prefManager = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
                if (MyPreferences.isFirst(getApplicationContext()) ||!databaseOperations.checkUser(databaseOperations)) {
                    launchHomeScreen();

                }else {
                    if(flag){
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainDrawer.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
                        finish();
                    }
                    flag=false;

                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not removing the listener when the activity gets stopped.  It will stay registered and listening for auth events if you don't remove it.  An auth token refresh (which happens automatically every hour) could trigger the listener.

Typically, you add listeners during onStart and remove them during onStop.  Always remove in parallel with your adds.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
    }